# Reading query from the table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the query below. When I write it in a code, I can execute it.

```
sSql  CLOB  := 'SELECT SUBSTR(NVL((SELECT b.DESC FROM LOCATION b WHERE b.LOCATION_ID = e.LOCATION_ID),0) || ''          '', 1, 10) AS BEZ, 
                           TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(MY_DAY,''j''), ''yyyymmdd'') AS TAG, 
                           SUBSTR(''000000'' || TO_CHAR(MY_CNT), -5, 5) AS MY_CNT
                      FROM (SELECT a.LOCATION_ID, 
                                   a.MY_DAY, 
                                   a.MY_CNT 
                              FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as MY_CNT, MY_DAY, LOCATION_ID
                                      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MY_DAY, SENDUNGSNR, LOCATION_ID
                                              FROM TAB_1 
                                             WHERE TAB_1_ID = :n1
                                               AND ISTGP_ID != 20545
                                               AND LOCATION_ID IN (SELECT LOCATION_ID FROM LOCATION WHERE M1 = 745)
                                           ) 
                                  GROUP BY LOCATION_ID, MY_DAY) a 
                           ) e 
                ORDER BY NVL((SELECT DESC FROM LOCATION b WHERE b.LOCATION_ID = e.LOCATION_ID), 0), MY_DAY';
```

This works fine

```
dbms_sql.parse(nCursorId, sSql, dbms_sql.native);
DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE (nCursorId, 'n1', '25');
```

But I wish to read this query from the table. How should I save it in a table field? I have tried many various ways(with apostrophe at the beginning, without apostrophe at the beginning etc). But every time the parsing fails.

1. How should I save it to be able to execute it?
2. How can I show where the query is incorrect?

Comment: `insert into some_table(some_clob_column) values ('<your query as is which successfully passes dbms_sql.parse>')`?

Comment: "How should I save it to be able to execute it?" You do not need to save the CLOB to be able to execute it.

Comment: "How can I show where the query is incorrect?" `DESC` is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/olaxs/reserved-words.html#GUID-7AA16E7F-A9CC-47EE-94B0-05C518D69BA7). You cannot use it as an (unquoted) identifier.

Comment: @astentx you can put it as answer. It works.

Comment: @MTO oh, indeed. DESC is a reserved word. But it was just a mistake as i simplified the query... But I wanted to know if there is any general way to show the errors and mark where the errors occures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I show where the query is incorrect?

`DESC` is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/olaxs/reserved-words.html#GUID-7AA16E7F-A9CC-47EE-94B0-05C518D69BA7), you cannot use it as an (unquoted) identifier.

> How should I save it to be able to execute it?

You do not need to save it to be able to execute it, just execute it using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` or `DBMS_SQL`:

```sql
DECLARE
  sSql  CLOB  := 'SELECT SUBSTR(NVL((SELECT b."DESC" FROM LOCATION b WHERE b.LOCATION_ID = e.LOCATION_ID),0) || ''          '', 1, 10) AS BEZ, 
                           TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(MY_DAY,''j''), ''yyyymmdd'') AS TAG, 
                           SUBSTR(''000000'' || TO_CHAR(MY_CNT), -5, 5) AS MY_CNT
                      FROM (SELECT a.LOCATION_ID, 
                                   a.MY_DAY, 
                                   a.MY_CNT 
                              FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as MY_CNT, MY_DAY, LOCATION_ID
                                      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MY_DAY, SENDUNGSNR, LOCATION_ID
                                              FROM TAB_1 
                                             WHERE TAB_1_ID = :n1
                                               AND ISTGP_ID != 20545
                                               AND LOCATION_ID IN (SELECT LOCATION_ID FROM LOCATION WHERE M1 = 745)
                                           ) 
                                  GROUP BY LOCATION_ID, MY_DAY) a 
                           ) e 
                ORDER BY NVL((SELECT "DESC" FROM LOCATION b WHERE b.LOCATION_ID = e.LOCATION_ID), 0), MY_DAY';
  v_bez SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
  v_tag SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
  v_cnt SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sSQL BULK COLLECT INTO v_bez, v_tag, v_cnt USING 1;
  
  FOR i IN 1 .. v_bez.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_bez(i) || ', ' || v_tag(i) || ', ' || v_cnt(i) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

If you do want to save it then:

```sql
DECLARE
  sSQL CLOB := '<your query>';
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table_name (clob_column) VALUES (sSql);
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=54396a4ac9b1f916562ba293a676456c)*

Comment: Thanks for answer. I definitely want to use dbms_sql here.